# How do I open a file with a jar file?

Tags: java, file, jar, associations

I'm not trying to open a file once my program has run, ex. Using Desktop.open, I'm trying to make it so I can right-click a file, and choose "Open-with" and then choose my application. I then want the path to the file being opened to be passed as one of the args to my application. This could allow me to make, for example, a text editor, and not have to run the client program in order to run other files that it handles.

Comment: it'd be helpful if you mentioned which OS you'd like this to happen on...

Comment: I second @MarcB comment, the question is a bit vague.

Comment: Is it just me?  I smell "this question doesn't belong to here".

Comment: Well preferably any OS, but windows if not all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you click on a file and choose open with you should already be able to choose your application. Maybe it does not occoure in the list of suggested application but you could browse for it and it should start.

I dont know how it works on a linux system but on a windows system you get the file path into your application. The following example will print the path of the file you have opened with "open with":

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 
     System.out.println(args[0]);
}
```

Comment: I thought that'd work, I've got it set up to open a window which displays the args passed to it, but if I try to choose open with -> myfile.jar it simply says it's "not a valid win32 application"

Comment: Ok, you cant open your file with the jar file. You could wrap your application in an exe-file or create a cmd-file which pass through your file parameter. Maybe this could help you: http://superuser.com/questions/125343/windows-open-with-with-java-and-a-jar-file